# How to list local files in a folder using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, file, file-access

I am a beginner using JavaScript in the past two days I am searching for a solution to access the list of files using Javascript but I could not find any solution.

**I am trying to build a web app that can show the list of the text files on the client's computer and then click it to open. If there is any other way to achieve this goal using another technology, please advise me which one would be the best.**

The operating system now I am using is windows it would be good if I could have the same functionality on all other operating systems.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you work in a browser, there is no way of accessing local files but the open-file-dialog.

Comment: in other words, a web app can't access the file system - this is a security measure (no, there is no secret workaround)

Comment: @Bravo  Then there is a big problem I thought I can give a folder path and let the web browser access all files inside it and this path would be the same for each client I mean all clients should create this path and place the text file there. when it is not possible it is very sad.

Comment: it may be said, but at least it's secure from script kiddies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is commented by @sirko and @Bravo it is not possible to give access to the files on the local drive with the browsers it is all because of security reasons. The only way to access files on the browser is to use the `input` tag with `"file"` attribute.